# How to use move group interface in a sub function?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Because my robot have 3 different targets need to reach in a loop, I want to merge the same line of each move group in a sub function to let the whole program more easy to read.

I think it will look like this:

```
void move_robot (moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface group, geometry_msgs::PoseStamped ObjectPose)
{
  group.setStartState(*group.getCurrentState());
  group.setPoseTarget(ObjectPose);

  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan group_Planer;
  bool success = (group.plan(group_Planer) == moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);
  if (success)
  {
    ros::Duration(1).sleep();
    group.execute(group_Planer);
  }
  group.clearPoseTargets();
  ros::Duration(1).sleep();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();

  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface group("manipulator");
  move_robot(group, pose1);
  move_robot(group, pose2);
  move_robot(group, pose3);

  return 0;
}
```

I got some error in this form, so I would like to know how to modify and run it.
Thank for your answer!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334689/how-to-use-move-group-interface-in-a-sub-function?/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the example code on MoveIt! tutorials website.

```
void move_robot (moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface &group, geometry_msgs::PoseStamped Pose)
{
  group.setStartState(*group.getCurrentState());
  group.setPoseTarget(Pose);

  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan group_Planer;
  bool success = (group.plan(group_Planer) == moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);
  if (success)
  {
    ros::Duration(1).sleep();
    group.execute(group_Planer);
  }
  group.clearPoseTargets();
  ros::Duration(1).sleep();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();

  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface group("manipulator");
  move_robot(group, pose1);
  move_robot(group, pose2);
  move_robot(group, pose3);

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) with karma: 37 on 2019-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0